# Cannot install Gimp 64 bit

Tags: package-management, 64-bit, 32-bit, gimp

I am trying to install Gimp on a 64 bit PC with Ubuntu 14.10. I have added the dedicated PPA

```
ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
```

but I am not able to install Gimp due to its reliance on a lot of 32 bit libraries (nor was I able without the PPA).

For instance it depends on `libgegl`, which does not seem to be in the repositories, according to Synaptic. I can find the debugging symbols `libgegl-0.2-0-dbg:i386`, but if I try to install those (not that they would help, just to see), I find that they depend on a lot of `i386` stuff, and this in turn would force me to remove a lot of important 64 bit libraries, such as `libblas3` or `liblapack3`, on which `numpy` depends. Same happens with other dependencies such as `libbabl`.

So, while there seems to be a 64 bit version of Gimp, it seems to rely on 32 bit libraries which are not installable in my system, and often do not appear into Synaptic at all.

What is the way to install Gimp?

**EDIT** As request, I post the terminal output

```
andrea@lafcadio:~$ LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libbabl-0.1-0 (>= 0.1.10) but it is not installable
        Depends: libgegl-0.2-0 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.3.10) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please put the list of output of your terminal when you try installing Gimp

Comment: Why you add external repo whilst you can just `sudo apt-get install gimp`?

Comment: I added the terminal output. The reason I added the PPA was that Synaptic would not even show Gimp before. And if I tried to install that on the terminal,  I would get an error, similar (if not the same) to the one I just posted. Inspecting the broken dependencies I started seeing some `i386` versions, so I thought that the official repositories did not have a 64 bit Gimp, and I looked for a more up-to-date version

Comment: Since [`libgegl-0.2-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgegl-0.2-0),  [`libbabl-0.1-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libbabl-0.1-0) and [`libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0) have 64-bit versions, your problem is elsewhere. Also, please use `LC_ALL=C` while running commands to post output here, so that we can get output in English.

Comment: @muru Well, if they exist, they certainly do not show up in Synaptic. There, I only find 32 bit versions

Comment: did you try to manually install those packages?

Comment: check it with `apt-cache` e.g.: `apt-cache policy libgegl-0.2-0` or without version if it's installed then purge it `apt-get remove --purge packagename` and install it back.

Comment: These packages are not installed right now. If I try to install them with apt-get,  I get a long list of dependencies on `i386` packages which forces me to remove 64 bit packages such as `liblapack3` or `python3-numpy`

Comment: @muru sorry, I did not know of that flag

Comment: When you run `sudo apt-get update`, do you see any mentions of amd64 repositories? What does `dpkg --print-architecture` say?

Comment: `~dpkg --print-architecture` returns `amd64`. I am now running `sudo apt-get update`, and it does mention amd 64 repos, but it is running unexpectedly slow. It seems to be stuck `[Waiting for headers]`

Comment: Ok, after `sudo apt-get update` I get a bunch of errors ,which are either `failed stat (2: file or directory not existent)` or `Impossible to retrieve http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages: hashsum not corresponding` - and same for other repos

Comment: Switching away from the italian servers to the main ones seems to fix everything. I guess something is broken now in the italian mirror

Comment: Reviewers: Since this question is answered and switching to a different mirror is *often* a way of solving this sort of problem, I don't think we should consider this to be off-topic as "a problem that cannot be reproduced." (There might be a question somewhere we could close this as a duplicate of.)

Answer (score 5):

Switching away from the Italian servers to the main ones seems to fix everything. I guess something is broken now in the Italian mirror.